# How to correctly use std::map<int, std::map<POINTER, STRUCT>> in SWIG?

Tags: swig

How to correctly use `std::map<int, std::map<POINTER, STRUCT>>` in SWIG when target is C#.

From documentation, tried using

```
namespace std 
    {
        %template(map_POINTER_STRUCT) map<POINTER, STRUCT>;
        %template(map_int_map_POINTER_STRUCT) std::map<int, std::map<POINTER, STRUCT>>;
    }
```

But SWIG still gives error `Error: Syntax error in input(3)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to SWIG and older C++ compilers mistaking `>>` for the right-shift operator.  Insert a space:

```
%template(map_int_map_POINTER_STRUCT) std::map<int, std::map<POINTER, STRUCT> >;
                                                                             ^
                                                                          here
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't expected that could be causing problem.